# How to delete a common word from large number of datas in a Postgres table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table in Postgres. In that table more than 1000 names are there. Most of the names are start with SHRI or SMT. I want to delete this SHRT and SMT from the names and to save original name only. How can I do that with out any database function?

Comment: er.."How can i do that with out any database function?"  - quick clarify...are you saying you don't want to create a function, or are you saying you can't use database functions like substring()?  Not sure if you could do this without using functions to read the string.

Comment: ya i don't want to create function.but in built functions can be used.

Answer (score 1):

I'll step you through the logic:

```
Select left(name,3) from table
```

This select statement will bring back the first 3 chars of a column (the 'left' three).  If we are looking for SMT in the first three chars, we can move it to the where statement

```
 select * from table where left(name,3) = 'SMT'
```

Now from here you have a few choices that can be used.  I'm going to keep to the left/right style, though replace could likely be used.  We want the chars to the right of the SMT, but we don't know how long each string is to pick out those chars.  So we use length() to determine that.

```
select right(name,length(name)-3) from table where left(name,3) = 'SMT'
```

I hope my syntax is right there, I'm lacking a postgres environment to test it.  The logic is 'all the chars on the right of the string except the last 3 (the minus 3 excludes the 3 chars on the left.  change this to 4 if you want all but the last 4 on the left)

You can then change this to an update statement (set name = right(name,length(name)-3) ) to update the table, or you can just use the select statement when you need the name without the SMT, but leave the SMT in the actual data.